# Cohomology of n-Sphere by Mayer Vietoris sequence

Tags: homology-cohomology, spheres, de-rham-cohomology

According to the method in

https://planetmath.org/exampleofcohomologyandmayervietorissequence

The Mayer-Vietoris sequence

$0\rightarrow H^m(S^{n-1})\rightarrow
H^{m+1}(S^n)\rightarrow0$.

is obtained. I understood by this short exact sequence the isomorphism

$H^{m+1}(S^n)\simeq H^m(S^{n-1})$

is obtained. By induction,

$H^p(S^n)\simeq H^{p-n+1}(S^1)
\simeq \delta_{p,n}\mathbb R$
($\because H^1(S^1)=\mathbb R$).

But I don’t understand why this reduction formula is not valid for $p=n-1$.
In this case,
$H^{n-1}(S^n)\simeq H^0(S^1)$ and since $H^0(S^1) = \mathbb R$, I conclude that
$H^{n-1}(S^n) = \mathbb R$.
Why is it not correct?

The correct answer is
\begin{equation}
H^p(S^n)
= \begin{cases}
 \mathbb R & p = 0,n\\
 0 & \text{others}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact sequence holds for $m >0$, not for $m=0$. Because the beginning of the long sequence is $0 \to H^0(S^{n+1})\to H^0(A) \oplus H^0(B) \to H^0(S^n) \to H^1(S^{n+1})$, but $H^0(A)$ and $H^0(B)$ are not zero (they are $\simeq \mathbb{R}$) and the range of $ H^0(A) \oplus H^0(B) \to H^0(S^n)$ is not zero (actually it is all $H^0(S^n)$)

Comment: If one wants an exact sequence that holds even for $m=0$, one should use *reduced* cohomology. (In fact, with reduced cohomology, exactness holds for $m<0$, too!)

Comment: Indeed. But I just answered the question for the usual cohomology ^^

Comment: For $p=0$ case the sequence becomes 
\begin{equation}
0\longrightarrow H^0(S^1)
\overset{(i^*,j^*)}\longrightarrow\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R
\overset{k^*-\ell^*}\longrightarrow\mathbb R\oplus\mathbb R
\overset{d_*}\longrightarrow H^1(S^1)
\longrightarrow0,
\end{equation}

The maps are defiend by the inclusions:
\begin{equation}
i: U\rightarrow S^1,\;\;
j: V\rightarrow S^1,\;\;
k: U\cap V\rightarrow U,\;\;
\ell: U\cap V\rightarrow V.
\end{equation}

Comment: The image and kernel of the difference map $k^*-\ell^*$ is one-dimensional respectively and $\text{im}(k^*-\ell^*) = \ker d_*$ by the exactness.  
Then 
\begin{equation}
H^1(S^1) = \text{im}(d_*) 
= H^1(U\cap V)/(\ker d_*)
= (R\oplus R)/\text{im}(k^*-\ell^*)
= (R\oplus R)/R
= \mathbb R.
\end{equation}
The map $(i^*,j^*)$ is injective and $\text{im}(i^*,j^*) = \ker(k^*-\ell^*)$ by the exactness.
Then 
\begin{equation}
H^1(S^1)\simeq H^0(U)\oplus \text{im}(i^*,j^*) 
= \ker(k^*-\ell^*) = R.
\end{equation}

Comment: Then we found 
\begin{equation}
H^0(S^1) = H^1(S^1) = \mathbb R.
\end{equation}

Comment: I rethought the $p=0$ case and found the correct result but I still don't have a confidence that I understood clearly. 
For example, why is the map $k^*-\ell^*$, 
$H^0(U)\oplus H^0(V)\rightarrow H^0(U\cap V)$ is ``one dimensional"?
I think this map is given by a form $\omega\in H^0(U)\oplus H^0(V)$ as
$\omega\rightarrow (k^*\omega-\ell^*\omega)\in H^0(U\cap V)$.
The image is one-dimensional, since this form has basis $dx$ and
$k^*\omega - \ell^*\omega$ is zero if $\omega$ agrees on $U\cap V$:
$H^0(U\cap V)\supset\omega\simeq R$.

Please point out if my thoughts are incorrect.

Comment: The exact sequence you wrote is for $S^1$ and here $U \cap V$ is homothopic to $S^0$, that is two discrete points, so $H^0(U \cap V=\mathbb{R}^2$. But to link $S^n$ and $S^{n+1}$ for $n \geqslant 1$, the set $U \cap V$ is homotopic to $S^n$, so $H^0(U \cap V)= \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thank you so much ^_−☆